# Objective-C - Correct init method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, init

I have subclassed `UITableViewCell` and in the `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` I'm setting some instance variables like so:

```
_image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]
```

I'm not using any accessor because Apple recommends not using accessors in `init` and `dealloc`.

So far so good. My question is after I've set the _image I want to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for the image. Should I do it with the getter or should I use the ivar directly?

```
self.image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Or

```
_image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Which style is preferred of using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommendation still holds: use the ivar directly in init. If you ever implement a custom accessor on that property (now or later, here or when subclassing), you might be in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

[A third option](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakeAThirdOption): Assign the image to a local variable, set it up completely (e.g., its `userInteractionEnabled`) using that, and then assign it to the instance variable from the local variable.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is a property value, self.image... is more correct, it will make sure all notifications are sent and if anything else is observing the object is run. If you use _image... none of the notifications are sent.

Comment: This is actually bad practise in init and dealloc and can easily lead to errors. In fact, you don't want to trigger *anything* for an object that is not yet completely initialized!

Comment: +1 to @Eiko and also there shouldn't be any observers at this point in an object's lifecycle (except possibly for `self`, even then I don't think you'd want the notifications issued while half-initialized). You would have had to have done something like `obj = [Class alloc]; [obj addObserver...]; [obj init];` in which case you are probably better off not getting the notification anyway.

Comment: Why minus points ? My answer is totally correct, although some might say it is a bad practice, I just don't agree with that. This does not qualify for minus points.